# Spring MVC access path attributes value on page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

There is a field on webpage

```
<form:input id="startDate" onkeydown="return false;" readonly="readonly" path = "startDate"/>
```

And there is an anchor tag

```
<a id="excelDownload" target ="reportExcel" href ="downloadFIReport.do?startDate='start_date_goes_here'">Download As Excel</a>
```

How can i get "start_date_goes_here".

This date must be the date while page load ,not the one changed after page load.

Do i have to add this date using model.addAttribute("") ? Or there is some another way ?

Comment: Use normal string as date for e.g "20/11/2014"

Comment: path = "startDate" variable is of type date. I want to bind it with a bean

Comment: Use propertyEditors, http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use CustomDateEditor. First, the CustomDateEditor is created, that converts a String to java.util.Date. The format that will be used to parse the String to Date is also defined inside the CustomDateEditor bean definition.

```
<bean id="dateEditor"
    class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor">

    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
            <constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss;z" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="true" />

</bean>
```

Then the CustomEditorConfigurer is created to register the CustomDateEditor. It has a property named customEditors, that consists of a map with a java.util.Date key and a value that is a reference to the CustomDateEditor bean.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
        <property name="customEditors">
            <map>
                <entry key="java.util.Date">
                    <ref local="dateEditor" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now in initBinder method use it

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class,dateEditor);
super.initBinder(request, binder);
```

**UPDATE:**
Or if you just hate that configuration in xml file, you can directly register CustomDateEditor like this in InitBinder. This method should be written in controller.:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder( WebDataBinder binder){

     SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
            binder.registerCustomEditor( Date.class, new CustomDateEditor( simpleDateFormat,false));     

}
```

Comment: Where exactly i am supposed to write initBinder ?

Comment: Which Spring version you are using?

Comment: I am using Spring MVC 3.0

Comment: check the updated answer. It will work if Controller expects date to come.

Answer (score 1):

In spring MVC the model is where the controller puts anything that will be used by the view.

As you want to use the date :

- in a link
- with its initial value

the simpler way it to put in in the model, and directly use it in the form.

Controller

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

@RequestMapping(...)
public String show_the_view(Model model) {
    // get and format the date
    model.addAttribute("startdate", dateFormat.format(new Date());
    ...
    return "view_name";
}
```

View :

```
<a id="excelDownload" target ="reportExcel"
      href ="downloadFIReport.do?startDate='${startdate}'">Download As Excel</a>
```

EDIT

With the code you gave in comment (and that you should have given directly in question ...), provided `fiReportSearchInput.getStartDate()` is a `java.util.Date` , it would give :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "downloadFIReport.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadFIBill(ModelMap model,
        @ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") FIReportSearchInput fiReportSearchInput,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println(fiReportSearchInput.getStartDate() + " "
        + fiReportSearchInput.getEndDate());
    ModelMap.addAttribute("startdate",
        dateFormat.format(fiReportSearchInput.getStartDate());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi this value is then sent to a controller where startDate is expected to be a java.util.Date. Not sure if it will work in that case. Here is the controllers Code.  @RequestMapping(value = "downloadFIReport.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public void downloadFIBill(ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") FIReportSearchInput fiReportSearchInput,HttpServletResponse response) {
  
  System.out.println(fiReportSearchInput.getStartDate() + "     " +  fiReportSearchInput.getEndDate());